# WPF C# Feathering image edges

Tags: c#, wpf, image-manipulation

How would I go about feathering the top and bottom of an image in a WPF c#.

Can I do this dynamically ? I am asking because the images are generated dynamically (from the c# code and not in the XAML code).

Do i need to install any NuGet packages or any references?

Thanks,

Simon

Comment: What is feathering?  If a bitmap effect is needed do any of the standard ones help [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743435.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743435.aspx)?

Comment: It would be like this: http://hiratadigital.com/individual/vignettes.jpg

Comment: Sorry. Don't know how to do that.  There are some paths worth investigating.  Break the image into separate segments and apply a standard bitmap effect to each segment as desired.  Or, if the standard bitmap effects cannot be used perhaps there is a way to do it with a [Custom Bitmap Effect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms771475(v=vs.90).aspx) of your own making.